# C6386 Warning "Buffer overrun"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, g++

I have a Warning  C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'res_str.str':  the writable size is '(res_str.length+1)*1' bytes, but '3' bytes might be written in my code
I use MVS 19, c++ 11 standard, g++ compiler.

```
tg_string operator+(const tg_string& add_str)
{
    tg_string res_str;
    res_str.length = this->length + add_str.length;
    res_str.str = new char[res_str.length+1];
    uint32_t i = 0;
    for (; i < this->length; i++)
    {
        res_str.str[i] = this->str[i];
    }
    for (uint32_t j = 0; j < (add_str.length); j++, i++)
    {
        res_str.str[i] = add_str.str[j];
    }
    res_str.str[res_str.length] = '\0';
    return res_str;
}
```

Is it due to incorrect array filling or something else?

Comment: Something else I would say. Can't see any problem with the code above.

Comment: I guess your code is correct and the warning is a false positive. Consider using memcpy: memcpy(res_str.str, this->str, this->length); memcpy(res_str.str + this->length, add_str.str, add_str.length + 1);